# Gradle: custom task with jvm arguments for Spring Boot

Tags: gradle, build, spring-boot, jvm

Trying to create a small custom gradle task for Spring Boot that originally looks like this:

`gradle bootRun --debug-jvm`

The task should look like this: `gradle debugRun`

I tried this but it does not work:

```
task debugRun(dependsOn: 'bootRun') << {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['--debug-jvm']
}
```

How can I pass this debug-flag to the bootRun task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't sufficient for your `debug` run task to depend on the `bootRun` task. It needs to modify the existing `bootRun` task to enable debugging. You can do that by checking for the `debugRun` task in Gradle's task graph. If it's there, you set the `bootRun` task's `debug` property to `true`:

```
task debugRun(dependsOn:bootRun) {
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        if (graph.hasTask(debugRun)) {
            bootRun {
                debug = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I need. Thnx.