# How to run bootRun with Spring profile via Gradle task?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm trying to set up Gradle to launch the `bootRun` process with various Spring profiles enabled.

My current `bootRun` configuration looks like:

```
bootRun {
    // pass command line options from gradle to bootRun
    // usage: gradlew bootRun "-Dspring.profiles.active=local,protractor"
    if (System.properties.containsKey('spring.profiles.active')) {
        systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", System.properties['spring.profiles.active']
    }
}
```

I'd like to set system properties with a `gradle` task, and then execute `bootRun`.

My attempt looked like this:

```
task bootRunDev

bootRunDev  {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "Dev")
}
```

A few questions:

1. Is `systemProperty` a part of the Spring Boot bootRun configuration?
2. Is it possible to set a system property in another task?
3. What should my next step be? I need to get `bootRunDev` configuration to happen before `bootRun`?
4. Is there another approach I should look into?

-Eric

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Spring Boot v2 [Gradle plugin docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/) provide an answer:

> 6.1. Passing arguments to your application
>
> Like all JavaExec tasks, arguments can be passed into bootRun from the command line using `--args='<arguments>'` when using **Gradle 4.9 or later**.

To run server with active profile set to *dev*:

```
$ ./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'
```

Comment: This definitely works, can you please tell me how can i pass these in bootJar task

Comment: Does this still work?

Answer (score 83):

Environment variables can be used to set spring properties as described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config). So, to set the active profiles (`spring.profiles.active`) you can use the following code on Unix systems:

```sh
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test gradle clean bootRun
```

And on Windows you can use:

```sh
SET SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test
gradle clean bootRun
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: On *nix, you will probably need to export the variable for it to be visible to gradle: `export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev; gradle bootRun`

Comment: No, on a per-call basis setting environment variables works as shown by david.

Comment: It does work on Windows! In my case, I was not even running bootRun, but executing `SpringBootTest` tests that require the active profiles for retrieving properties via spring-cloud-config.

Answer (score 69):

Simplest way would be to define default and allow it to be overridden. I am not sure what is the use of systemProperty in this case. Simple arguments will do the job.

```
def profiles = 'prod'

bootRun {
  args = ["--spring.profiles.active=" + profiles]
}
```

To run dev:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Pdev
```

To add dependencies on your task you can do something like this:

```
task setDevProperties(dependsOn: bootRun) << {
  doFirst {
    System.setProperty('spring.profiles.active', profiles)
  }
}
```

There are lots of ways achieving this in Gradle.

Edit:

Configure separate configuration files per environment.

```
if (project.hasProperty('prod')) {
  apply from: 'gradle/profile_prod.gradle'
} else {
  apply from: 'gradle/profile_dev.gradle'
}
```

Each configuration can override tasks for example:

```
def profiles = 'prod'
bootRun {
  systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", profiles
}
```

Run by providing `prod` flag in this case just like that:

```
./gradlew <task> -Pprod
```

Comment: I get `Could not find method dev() for arguments [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.` when I try this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31328621/1134197 works fine

Comment: While first code snippet shows how to configure `bootRun` task, other examples simply do not work.

Comment: Can you update how `-Pdev` will set `profiles` to `dev`? It seems it does not work at all.

Comment: You obviously need to have 'org.springframework.boot' plugin applied to your project as well.

Comment: For anyone confused about `-P` see [Passing System properties to your application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application-passing-system-properties) on the Spring website. It allows properties to be passed to the JVM.

Answer (score 17):

Using this shell command it will work:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test gradle clean bootRun
```

Sadly this is the simplest way I have found.
It sets environment property for that call and then runs the app.

Comment: Just x but where do I put that ? sorry but i down vote your question

Comment: Directly in the shell. The first part defines an env variable, then Gradle command. No need to downvote man.

Comment: I also think this is the simplest way. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 15):

For those folks using Spring Boot 2.0+, you can use the following to setup a task that will run the app with a given set of profiles.

```
task bootRunDev(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
    group = 'Application'

    doFirst() {
        main = bootJar.mainClassName
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev'
    }
}
```

Then you can simply run `./gradlew bootRunDev` or similar from your IDE.

Comment: how we can customize webapp folder for this task..?

Answer (score 13):

For the command line as of Gradle 7.5 and Spring Boot 2.7.3, I do this (if it helps anyone):

```
gradle bootRun --args=--spring.profiles.active=myprofile
```

Answer (score 10):

**Kotlin** edition: Define the following task in you `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
tasks.BootRun {
  args("--spring.profiles.active=dev")
}
```

This will pass the parameter `--spring.profiles.active=dev` to `bootRun`, where the profile name is `dev` in this case.

Every time you run `gradle bootRun` the profile `dev` is used.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted it simple just to be able to call gradle bootRunDev like you without having to do any extra typing..

This worked for me - by first configuring it the bootRun in my task and then right after it running bootRun which worked fine for me :)

```
task bootRunDev {
    bootRun.configure {
        systemProperty "spring.profiles.active", 'Dev'
    }
}

bootRunDev.finalizedBy bootRun
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone looking how to do this in Kotlin DSL, here's a working example for `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.register("bootRunDev") {
    group = "application"
    description = "Runs this project as a Spring Boot application with the dev profile"
    doFirst {
        tasks.bootRun.configure {
            systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev")
        }
    }
    finalizedBy("bootRun")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In your `build.gradle` file simply use the following snippet

```
bootRun {
  args = ["--spring.profiles.active=${project.properties['profile'] ?: 'prod'}"]
}
```

And then run following command to use `dev` profile:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Pprofile=dev
```

Answer (score 4):

For someone from internet, there was a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35848666/906265 I do provide the modified answer from it here as well:

```
// build.gradle
<...>

bootRun {}

// make sure bootRun is executed when this task runs
task runDev(dependsOn:bootRun) {
    // TaskExecutionGraph is populated only after 
    // all the projects in the build have been evaulated https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#whenReady-groovy.lang.Closure-
    gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph ->
        logger.lifecycle('>>> Setting spring.profiles.active to dev')
        if (graph.hasTask(runDev)) {
            // configure task before it is executed
            bootRun {
                args = ["--spring.profiles.active=dev"]
            }
        }
    }
}

<...>
```

then in terminal:

```
gradle runDev
```

Have used `gradle 3.4.1` and `spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE`

Answer (score 4):

Configuration for 4 different task with different profiles and gradle tasks dependencies:

- `bootRunLocal` and `bootRunDev` - run with specific profile
- `bootPostgresRunLocal` and `bootPostgresRunDev` same as prev, but executing custom task `runPostgresDocker` and `killPostgresDocker` before/after bootRun

`build.gradle`:

```
final LOCAL='local'
final DEV='dev'

void configBootTask(Task bootTask, String profile) {
    bootTask.main = bootJar.mainClassName
    bootTask.classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    bootTask.args = [ "--spring.profiles.active=$profile" ]
//    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', profile // this approach also may be used
    bootTask.environment = postgresLocalEnvironment
}

bootRun {
    description "Run Spring boot application with \"$LOCAL\" profile"
    doFirst() {
        configBootTask(it, LOCAL)
    }
}

task bootRunLocal(type: BootRun, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    description "Alias to \":${bootRun.name}\" task: ${bootRun.description}"
    doFirst() {
        configBootTask(it, LOCAL)
    }
}

task bootRunDev(type: BootRun, dependsOn: 'classes') {
    description "Run Spring boot application with \"$DEV\" profile"
    doFirst() {
        configBootTask(it, DEV)
    }
}

task bootPostgresRunLocal(type: BootRun) {
    description "Run Spring boot application with \"$LOCAL\" profile and re-creating DB Postgres container"
    dependsOn runPostgresDocker
    finalizedBy killPostgresDocker
    doFirst() {
        configBootTask(it, LOCAL)
    }
}

task bootPostgresRunDev(type: BootRun) {
    description "Run Spring boot application with \"$DEV\" profile and re-creating DB Postgres container"
    dependsOn runPostgresDocker
    finalizedBy killPostgresDocker
    doFirst() {
        configBootTask(it, DEV)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to VM options:
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Or you can add it to the build.gradle file to make it work: bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties.

Comment: This needs to be added to the `build.gradle` file to make it work: `bootRun.systemProperties = System.properties`. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/832#issuecomment-272780482

Answer (score 2):

my way:

in gradle.properties:

```
profile=profile-dev
```

in build.gradle add VM options -Dspring.profiles.active:

```
bootRun {
   jvmArgs = ["-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS","-Dspring.profiles.active="+profile]
}
```

this will override application **spring.profiles.active** option

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work with Kotlin Gradle DSL. `bootRun` shows on red.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution for Spring Boot 2.5+

```
tasks.register('runDev') {
   dependsOn 'bootRun'
   bootRun.systemProperty('spring.profiles.active', 'dev')
}
```

and to run:

```
./gradlew runDev
```

Answer (score 2):

For Gragle Kotlin, following works for me

```
tasks.bootRun {
    args("--spring.profiles.active=dev")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jib for containerisation then,
Add these two line of codes in your build.gradle and application.properties files respectively.

```
jib.container.jvmFlags = ['-Dspring.profiles.active=test']
spring.profiles.active=test
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (February 2024), this works for me. It sets a default active profile every time I run Spring Boot, and also allows me to override the profile from the command line.

```
bootRun {
  systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', findProperty('spring.profiles.active') ?: 'development'
}
```

Then from the command line, I can override the active profile(s) with...

```
./gradlew -Pspring.profiles.active=staging
```

...replacing "staging" with a comma-delimited list of profiles as needed If I don't pass anything, it defaults to the "development" profile.

How it works: The `-Pspring.profiles.active` sets a Gradle *project* property, which is then used in the bootRun block above to set a *system* property for the Spring Boot application itself. If the *project* property is not found, it defaults to setting the application's system property to "development".

I found this technique very clearly explained in the Spring Boot Gradle Plugin doc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#running-your-application.passing-system-properties.