# Design for Spring Boot War to be Deployed to multiple JBoss EAP 7.1 Environments

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build, jboss7.x

We have JBoss EAP 7.1 servers in Dev/Test/Prod environments and we want to build a war for each of the environments and deploy them in the individual environments.

If I wish to run bootRun, there are simple solutions (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44666897/5631863).

However, I cannot run the application from command line, and I can only deploy a war on my JBoss.

How can I do a build with the profiles baked into it? Something like the following:

```
gradle clean build -PactiveProfile=dev
gradle clean build -PactiveProfile=test
gradle clean build -PactiveProfile=prod
```

Comment: If the answers in the duplicate don’t work for you, you should ask a question showing exactly how you’ve tried to use that approach and the behaviour that you’re getting

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - The solution in the link above worked for me. Thanks.