# How to pass environment variables to the gradle wrapper build using only command line?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, command-line, environment-variables

I am trying to pass env variables locally with strictly a command line command. At deploy, these variables get passed into the docker container, but when running locally, they are not present and need to be set locally.

They need to be removed before committing though because they are access keys so i dont want them exposed in the repo. That is why running tests locally (without an IDE) would require a command that passes these variables.

I have already tried this:

```
./gradlew clean build -Dspring.profiles.active=local -DMY_ENV_VAR1=xxxxxx -DMY_ENV_VAR2=xxxxxx
```

and it doesnt seem to be working. i cant find the docs for the build command's options, but i thought this was how you pass them. what am i doing wrong here? or is it not possible?

Answer (score 32):

For passing env variables

`MY_ENV_VAR1=xxxxxx MY_ENV_VAR2=xxxxxx ./gradlew bootRun`

For arguments/overriding properties values

`./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=local --db.url=something --anotherprop=fafdf'`

For both passing env variable and overriding properties values.

`MY_ENV_VAR1=xxxxxx MY_ENV_VAR2=xxxxxx ./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=local --db.url=something --anotherprop=fafdf'`

Comment: and now a version that works in powershell or cmd shell, please?

Comment: seems that --args is provided by the bootRun task. I assumed it was a gradle parameter, so was trying to use it with the integrationTest task, but it's not supported

Answer (score 32):

Another reason for environment variables not working is the gradle daemon.

Run this to kill any old daemons:

```
./gradlew --stop
```

Then try again. Lost far too much time on that.

Comment: Thank you for this! This answer needs a lot more upvotes to bubble it up higher...

Comment: We upgraded the Gradle version and when next trying to run it required a daemon restart. Thanks @matt burns

Comment: omg thanks a lot, I was even dreaming about this issue, this works on Android Studio Chipmunk and Gradle Wrapper 6.7.1

Answer (score 9):

This related post worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890208/1441210

The solution was to use the `--args` option of `gradlew` to get the environment variable to be passed to the spring boot app:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=local'
```

Comment: and the "--" within the string is necessary?

Comment: @heug indeed it is!

Comment: `./../gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=angular'` is not working for me.. it's only working if I set `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` but I can't use this because I have to run this in a gradle.build.. somebody fml ..

Comment: this is not the right answer. check my answer for the correct value

Answer (score 7):

If you want to pass values to the JVM that runs the gradle you can use the '-D' switch. I suppose you have to pass values to the gradle build file from the command line. If that's the case there are two options for that:

1. You can use the -P switch and specify the value there. For example:

   `gradle -PmySecretKey="This key is so secret" yourTask`
2. If you are using linux or variants you can set environment variable as follows:

   `export ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_mySecretKey="This key is so secret"`

After this you can access the value in the gradle build file as follows (*I am using kotlin dsl*)

```
val mySecretKey: String by project

println(mySecretKey)
```

Comment: It says project can't be used as delegate. Did Kotlin DSL changed since the answer?

Answer (score 5):

I just put the env variable setting before calling command as the way a regular Unix shell does. Work with my Zsh.

`MY_ENV_VAR1=xxxxxx MY_ENV_VAR2=xxxxxx gradlew clean test`

Comment: but those they do not get passed to my Java application, if I do `MY_ENV=xxxxx ./gradlew buil`. Then in my Java application `MY_ENV` is null. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score -2):

To answer your question, as far as I know, there's no way to set environment variables manually through Gradle. What your doing right now is just passing in regular CLI arguments/parameters to your tests.

> when running locally, they are not present and need to be set locally.
>
> running tests locally (without an IDE) would require a command that passes these variables.

I see from your snippet, you are using Spring, likely Spring Boot. And since you're already specifying the profile as `local`, why not define these variables in a profile specific configuration? Example:

`application.yml` -- base configuration

```
my-config-value: ${MY_ENV_VAR}
```

`application-local.yml` -- `local` profile configuration that overrides the base

```
my-config-value: some-dummy-value-for-local-development
```

Comment: setting local env vars in spring is very simple and i know how to do that, i am asking this question because theres a specific case (for PR build checks at my enterprise) for it long story short