# Spring Boot Profile Gradle

Tags: spring-boot

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038250/setting-active-profile-and-config-location-from-command-line-in-spring-boot), I run my Spring Boot application with

```
./gradlew bootRun -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo
```

A component with the profile doesn't run. And I try to verify the active profile with the following code in the root Application class

```
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @PostConstruct
  void postConstruct(){
    String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
    log.info("active profiles: {}", 
    Arrays.toString(activeProfiles));
  }
```

The log message output is blank.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=foo` only works with maven. So it will not work with gradle. You can find informaiton on how to bootrun with gradle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923288/how-to-run-bootrun-with-spring-profile-via-gradle-task).

Comment: Thanks for the info.