# Configuration of SpringBoot application using TestNG

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testng

I'm learning spring boot and have some tests using TestNG which run just fine when running from the IntelliJ Run Configuration, in which I pass: `spring.profiles.active=dev` as one of several Environment Variables.

In my Groovy Pipeline I have:
`sh "./gradlew clean build test -Dspring.profiles.active=dev --no-daemon"`

I have a properties file under `src/main/resources`:

`application-dev.properties`

My Spring Boot base class under `src/test/java` is as follows:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootTestBase extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    public static Date date = new Date();
    public static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");
    public static String dt = formatter.format(date);
    public static ExtentSparkReporter spark;
    public static ExtentTest test;
    public static ExtentReports extent;
    public static String reportDestination = "build/test-results/report_" + dt + ".html";

    @BeforeSuite 
    public void testReport(){
        spark = new ExtentSparkReporter(reportDestination);
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(spark);

        spark.config().setDocumentTitle("Smoke Tests");
        spark.config().setReportName("Smoke Tests");
        spark.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        spark.config().setTimeStampFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm a '('zzz')'");
    }

    @Override
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    protected void springTestContextPrepareTestInstance() throws Exception {
        super.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.fail(result.getName() + " test case is failed. " + "<span class='badge badge-danger'> Fail </span>" + result.getThrowable());

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            test.skip(result.getName() + " test case is skipped." + "<span class='badge badge-warning'> Skip </span>");

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            test.pass(result.getName() + " test case is Passed." + "<span class='badge badge-success'> Success </span>");
        }
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown(){
        extent.flush();
    }
```

My Test Classes extend from this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class SmokeTestOne extends SpringBootTestBase {
// test code
```

My main App under `src/main/java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MongoAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SmokeTestsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(SmokeTestsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In Jenkins, the failure is: `No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default` and then a bunch of failure to Autowire beans, presumably because it cannot find the @Value attributes that need to know the active profile (environment).

A beginners error no doubt, but what am I failing to do, configuration-wise?

Comment: Try passing the active profile as an env var as: `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew clean build test --no-daemon`

Comment: [Other good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36925752/2834978)