# Java application.yml not picking up Environment Variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am trying to set environment variables and use them in application.yml of my spring-boot application.

System/OS: windows
Terminal: Git Bash

#### application.yml

```yaml
datasource:
    url: ${DATABASE_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false}
    username: ${DATABASE_USERNAME:root}
    password: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD:admin}
```

Now, to set these environment variables, i did following steps

1. create .env file with these environment varaibles

```
PORT=8000
DATABASE_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false"
DATABASE_USERNAME=kp-usr-1
DATABASE_PASSWORD=Kpi987223oibnW
```

2. Use `source .env` command to set environment variables for the session

After `source .env` I can check and verify all env vars using `echo $DATABASE_URL` command,
but it is not picked up by application.yml ( when running `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew bootJar`)

If i set these environment variables in Windows Environment variables from Window settings, then everything works as expected.

Is there anything am i missing ? I want to load the environment variables from .env file for the current session of Java process.

- I tried multiple scripts, like reading lines from .env and calling export=$line, but that also didn`t worked.
- Running `export DATABASE_URL=abd; export DATABASE_USER=admin; TERM=cygwin ./gradlew test` works, but this is cumbersome, when we have too many varaibles.
- Note: I am using windows with git bash terminal

Comment: git's bash is just a cross-platform terminal emulator, it's not actually the OS itself, so when you invoke gradle on windows you're not running "a shell script in git bash", you're running gradle in Windows, in a new process, independent of git bash itself, and it only has access to the user's environment variables set for Windows. What you _can_ do is explicitly include any args that you need forward from your invocation by using the `--args` flag, because that way you explicitly pass values into gradle as part of its run. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923288/#57890208

Answer (score 0):

According the information that i have,when you set environment variable in Terminal,the variables are temporary belong to the Terminal you execute these command and not persistent.
These variables persistent location is the Windows registry.
At windows 10.
User environment variable location is **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment**.
System environment variables location is **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment**\

You can execute the follow code in windows script like .bat or .cmd to do the persistence.

```
//set a temporary simple name for system environment location
set MACHINEregpath=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
    
//set GOROOT = C:\go in the System environment and persistence it in Registry
reg add "%MACHINEregpath%" /v "GOROOT" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\go" /f
```